# UITabBarController and custom control acting as a tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a custom tab bar controller subclass and instead of a tab bar, I use a custom UIView.

The problem is that I cannot get my view controllers to appear. I see a white screen and the "tab" if I call

```
[super setViewControllers:]
```

I get really odd artefacts as far as appearance goes.

So instead I tried setting the `selectedViewController` directly. I've kind of drawn a blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need to see your example code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell me how you are having a custom view for tabs..

Have u removed tabBar & added ur custom tabView.? and keep in mind if remove your tabBar the whole tabBarController will be removed..

So you need to just hide the tabBar from tabBarController and add ur custom `UIView` in place of tabBar and everything works fine. You have to select the tab index programatically as per the button selection in your custom view.

Comment: Ok the problem seems to be in the setter (code added to my original question. I am using ARC.

Comment: show me the code how u r adding the custom tabBar on window.? and hw u r using the `tabBarController` in background.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use view Controller containment concept in order to implement custom tabbar.

```
 [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1

   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2

   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];

   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
```

You can also use my custom control
[Custom Tabbar Control](https://github.com/bhavya-kothari/BKSegmented-OR-TabbarViewController)